# How to regularly restore/ flush Wordpress database to Snapshot?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am building a demo for my WordPress plugin. I want this demo database to restore/flush to a particular snapshot/point in time ever hour or so, so that if users change settings/posts, they are restored every hour back to normal

How can I achieve this?
I am currently using multisite for the demo website

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the browser localStorage. It's pretty good for this kind of behaviour and really simple to put in place.
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage
gl.